# Is it possible to use one InputBox for two functions?

Tags: excel, inputbox

Hi is it possible to use one InputBox to have two functions? Otherwise I have to fill in information twice. I want it to filter (that already works) and also want to show it in a cell.

```
FilterCriteria = InputBox("Code")
Sheet3.Range("B" & n).Value = InputBox("Code") 



If FilterCriteria = "" Then Exit Sub
FilterCriteria = Replace(FilterCriteria, "*", "")
FilterCriteria = "*" & FilterCriteria & "*"
```

Comment: It would help to know what you're talking about. Is this Excel?

Comment: Sorry, yes this is Excel.

Comment: can you explain more? what do you mean by `to have two functions`? do you want to use one function twice of you want to input two separate functions at once?

Comment: If I fill in ABC123 into the Inputbox, it shoud search for ABC123 in a certain column in sheet 2 (this part works ) and also "print" ABC123 at sheet3 cell ("B" & n). Without using two InputBoxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
FilterCriteria = InputBox("Code")
Sheet3.Range("B" & n).Value = FilterCriteria
```